# Differnce between array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I tried to push a object into array. its successfully Inserted in array. 
what is difference between this three code.

```
Array.push(Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))))
Array.push(Object.assign({},Object))
Array.push(Object)
```

Comment: You only have functions here in the code ..?

Comment: First deep copies an Object object then pushes, second copies an Object then pushes and third just pushes an Object.

Comment: @Teemu I only need difference between this method

Comment: @ritaj just to further what you said - the second is a shallow copy. Although depending on the content of the objects, you might get more differences between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this code may not work ***if*** you've redefined your global objects - `Object.assign` is a static method, but because you're treating `Object` as an actual object (an instance of `Object`) then it won't be accessible via that method.

The code will only work if you rename the variables - I've just lowercased them - or if you realise that you're pushing the `Object` function to the array.

The first line:

```
array.push(Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))));
```

Will push a deep copy of `object` to the array. Deep copy means that there are no references - the two are completely different objects. Modifying the original `object` will not modify the deep copy of `object` inside `array`. The functions and methods will be stripped, as will all `undefined` values. Circular references (like `window.window.window...`) will also fail (because you're attempting to place an infinite amount of characters inside a string - never a good idea

The second line:

```
array.push(Object.assign({}, object));
```

Will push a *shallow copy* of `object` to `array`. This means that the properties on the object itself will be copied by value, but properties inside the nested objects will be copied by reference.

The third line:

```
array.push(object);
```

Will push a reference to `object` into `array`. This means that if `object` is modified, the `object` inside `array` will also be modified.

Comment: Maybe he is just pushing an Object function to an array, who said anything about reassigning?

Comment: "*Will push a deep copy of `object` to the array*" it will also prune stuff like functions and `undefined` properties. So it's not necessarily a perfect copy. It would also fail with circular references.

Comment: Of course circular references will fail @VLAZ - I forgot about the functions, I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.push(Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))))
```

It's having four different things -

1. **JSON.stringify** - When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string. So you basically convert your object into `String/searializing`. But here in your case you probably have a deeply nested `object` that is why you converting it to `string/searializing` it to clone it fully because `objects` are reference variable.
2. **JSON.parse** -  It's opposite of `stringify` When receiving data from a web server, the data is always a string. And as you are using `Object.assign` method which required object you need to convert you `cloned sting object` back to `object`.
3. **Object.assign** - method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object. Here you are copying your copied `object` to a `empty object - {}` with all the other `own properties/ proto properties`
4. **Array.push** -  Finally you are pushing your fresh object into an `array`

   ```
   Array.push(Object.assign({},Object))
   ```

Here you are  copying the address of `object` to new `empty object`, which then you push to an `array` however this is `reference` so any change to `object` inside this `array` will change the original `object` because you copied the address of the object.

```
Array.push(Object)
```

In this you are simply pushing the `object` address directly to `array` and any change there will modify original object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.push(Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))))
```

For the above example,

-You are making string from Object with JSON.stringify() and

-Making a new object from that string with JSON.parse() and

-Again making a new object with Object.assign() by passing new empty object {}.

-Here you clone the Object to new object and pushing it to the array.

```
Array.push(Object.assign({},Object))
```

For the above example,

-You are making a new object with Object.assign() by passing new empty object {}.

-Here you clone the Object to new object and pushing it to the array

```
Array.push(Object)
```

For the above example,

-You are just pushing the object to the array.

Comment: "*You are making string from Object with JSON.stringify()*" more specifically, it's serialising into JSON.